# Is it possible to replace DataGrid.GroupStyle with syncfusion:SfDataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, grouping, syncfusion

I can't find a way to replace `GroupStyle` from default DataGrid control.

[`Styles and Templates in WPF DataGrid`](https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/datagrid/styles-and-templates) page says that for styling I have to use `CaptionSummaryRow`.

All samples from documentation about styling of group's header that I was manage to find show only how to change text's color, fonts, etc. It's not even close to what I have with default control.

What I want is DataGrid with visually separated groups but without ugly expander in headers.

MCVE

```cs
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
 
        public SampleType[] Samples { get; } =
            new[]
            {
                new SampleType(1, "Value1"),
                new SampleType(1, "Value10"),
                new SampleType(2, "Value3"),
                new SampleType(3, "Value40"),
                new SampleType(3, "Value50"),
                new SampleType(3, "Value60"),
                new SampleType(1, "Value100"),
                new SampleType(1, "Value1000"),
            };
    }
 
    public class SampleType
    {
        public SampleType(int id, string value)
        {
            Id = id;
            Value = value;
        }
 
        public int Id { get; }
 
        public string Value { get; }
    }
```

```xml
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="items" Source="{Binding Samples}">
                <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Id" />
                </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
            <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Border
                                Margin="0,0,0,5"
                                BorderBrush="Black"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                CornerRadius="5">
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <DataGrid
            Grid.Row="2"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            HeadersVisibility="Column"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource items}}"
            SelectionMode="Single">
            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <DataGridRowsPresenter />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="20"
                    Binding="{Binding Id}"
                    Header="" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="*"
                    Binding="{Binding Value}"
                    Header="Value" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Are you using a `DataGrid` or an `SfDataGrid`? Which one does your question apply to?

Comment: @mm8 My question is applied to both of them. I'm trying to port `DataGrid` to `SfDataGrid`. I want to get the same result as in MCVE with `DataGrid` but with `SfDataGrid`

Comment: Then you need to define a custom template for the `CaptionSummaryRowControl`.

Comment: @mm8 I tried but wasn't able to do it properly. All my attempts resulted in empty groups. Can you help me with it ?

Comment: Please show what you have tried then and include a link to a reproducible and runnable sample.